# Are external diodes needed to protect these MOSFETs from back emf?

Tags: mosfet

(note: this post has been updated as suggested by members)

The schematic below shows a single coil to be pulsed by n & p FETs. Each FET has 100V ds breakdown and < 10 mOhm Rds. Vgs threshold is +/- 2V for each. Vgs max = +/- 20V. There is no possibility for both FETs to have low Rds at the same time.

[image: coil pulsing in either direction]

The objective of the circuit is to pulse a single coil in either direction. Each pulse should be considered independent of those prior - there is no timing relationship between pulses other than a minimum time interval between them. This is not a motor driver. Pulses aren't alternating. The coil is being used to repel a magnet. There will be significant concerns due to the magnet - I have a good understanding of those concerns and am only interested in the circuit provided (i.e. without magnet).

Once I know how to protect the FETs I will push the circuit right to the point where Vds is almost exceeded. I could get FETs of Vds max = 120V but  question would be the same with rails at +/- 60V instead of 50V. I could keep going until Rds is too large or FETs get too expensive, so these specific values aren't the point of my post. The idea is to push the limits while protecting the FETs.

The coil shown is ~ 40mH with internal resistance 140 ohms, but I am interested in general principles that work for variable coil parameters. Assume between 5mH and 100mH. Vdd may be as low as 12V and as high as 50V as I experiment with pulse widths, duty cycles and field strengths. I realize back EMF may be significant, and I'm not sure how to protect the FETs other than to just lower Vdd. Current demand per pulse will be way below FET capability.

Consider gate signals to be wired correctly. Assume the circuit is perfect on that side of the schematic - it will not be a challenge. (unfortunately I didn't state this well upon first posting and there was a lot of confusion on that point. many apologies to those that wasted time because of it).

Last point which I'm sure some will ask me regards pulse widths and duty cycle. The hope is to create pulses at widths between 0.1ms and 2ms. Duty cycle flexible depending on noise, heat, ringing and of effects from back EMF. The ideal case which I don't expect to achieve: 0.5ms pulses that aren't a terrible mess (some ringing/noise will be acceptable). Current between 0.15A and 0.5A. Duty cycle 0.3 max. The final result can be a bit off from this and I'll be happy.

Many thanks for everyone's help already, specifically DKNguyen and Bruce Abbott!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117352/discussion-on-question-by-hazyj-are-external-diodes-needed-to-protect-these-mosf).

Comment: Hazy the problems usually stem from inadequate assumptions stated then moving targets like adding 5.1k changes  the answer  to the "simple" question from Yes to No.  Then the question goes from bad to worse due to more missing assumptions.  Like is the load an inductor or a motor with inertia, then how much.   So it's not worth my time, even though I wasted it in this simulation https://tinyurl.com/y8tksez3   This a common fault to this site and the Socratic Method  ends up being a really long discussion of irrelevant info

Comment: All questions MUST include all the design requirements and assumptions or SPECS which are MISSING in the question. Purpose, inputs, outputs. (/w measureable parameters)  Keep it simple but complete.

Comment: changing load and f changes everything for power but not voltage with ratios , still no idea on purpose https://tinyurl.com/y9xe4kzn  -1

Comment: Basically your question is , what are the ratings of the Body Diodes... See datasheets  for Imax and mJ max @ I, L where E= 1/2I^2L and when will they protect, or not

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I was never asking about body diodes or anything so simple. I've explained quite a bit including purpose even after this was downvoted stifling chances that the new guy would have incentive to get himself up to speed. You have my objective in which I've stated you DO NOT need to know more. You assume too much to believe you do. Obviously I showed willingness to improve everything. We all start somewhere. Even you! You decided to "waste" your time to ensure that my willingness to improve means nothing, all of it resulting in where we're at now. Thanks!!

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 and I DO thank you for your time even if you think it was wasted. I'm not sure why you have a periodic input though. My schematic was always clear about this: two inputs independent of one another. pulses independent from one another but never at the same time. I can easily find solutions for the periodic case like a motor driver. I posted because this wasn't that. I'm sure you think I'm at fault for leading you to believe otherwise. I'm sure that I wasn't because on that point I was clear.

Comment: and of course there's a downvote again ensuring that I don't improve and come up to speed. don't pay attention to the new guy! we don't like people who enjoy learning!

Comment: What is the coil resistance?

Comment: @bruce resistance can and will span a good range. I know you won't like that answer, but bear with me. it's inline with my admittedly generally worded post. currently i have 40.8 mH coils @ 140 ohm. the diagram should show 140 instead of 1k. I didn't change that because although coil L & R are clearly important I may get other coils and have the same question. before you respond to what i just wrote, you may want to read answers and my comments to them, as there seems to be some general thinking that I don't understand something(s) basic. I assure you I do however.

Comment: @bruce assume you understand that the 1k resistor in the schematic can be replaced with 140 ohm for my current case. and why so wishy washy about this? because tomorrow I can purchase a coil with 1k ohm resistance and about 40 mH and the question will be the same. suffice to say my coils will be from 5mH to 100mH and from 100 ohms to 1000 ohms. the question is the same regardless. i'll push the rails and pulses and duty cycles to where it's the same question.

Comment: The reason I asked is that your specs are incompatible with the circuit you provided. Now that I know the expected range of inductance and resistance I can resolve those issues and complete my analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to pulse the electromagnet in alternately reversing polarities then you can either use a half-bridge:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1gu8W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or an H-bridge:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flxUcG.png)</sup>

You can use clamp diodes, TVS diodes, or RC snubbers or combinations thereof to control the inductive kick.

The vast majority of discrete MOSFETs have a parasitic body diode which can serve the same purpose as the rail-clamp diodes in an H-bridge but, being parasitic, they are usually not optimized for the purpose. External rail-clamp diodes will be better.

Rail clamp diodes *cannot* be used in the half-bridge configuration.

I repeat: Rail clamp diodes *cannot* be used in the half-bridge configuration, unless you feel like having the flyback current routed through your power supply.

- **Rail-clamp diodes (D1 to D4)** will clamp the voltage to the power supply rails. The diodes will have only low heat since they operate in forward bias but that means the energy stored in the magnetic field of the coil will be dissipated in the coil resistance (or R1 if you have it). Will not control dV/dT.
- **RC snubbers** Do not clamp to a fixed voltage. Instead they lower the voltage spike compared to what it would have otherwise been. Slow down dV/dT and are faster than diodes since they are "always on", but less efficient as a result. Use capacitors and resistors rated for pulse loads and with low parasitic inductance. Since it works by reducing dV/dT it will help if high dV/dT is causing MOSFET misbehaviour due to transient currents finding their way through the MOSFET parasitic capacitances whereas diodes will not.
- **TVS diodes (D5-D6)** Clamps the voltage across the coil to a fixed value. High power dissipation in the diodes since they operate in reverse breakdown. D1 and D2 here are two back-to-back unidirectional TVS diodes or you can use just one bidirectional TVS diode. Will not control dV/dT

For the H-bridge, you can also place TVS diodes or RC snubbers in parallel with the inductance similar to what was done in the half-bridge.

For the same power supply voltages (i.e. for the same 'V'), both half-bridge and H-bridge can apply the same voltage to the coil in both directions. However, the half-bridge requires only two power transistors but requires two voltage supplies whereas the H-bridge requires four power transistors but only one voltage supply.

Comment: Thanks!! You've been extremely helpful. I do want to clarify what I think is the key point of my circuit and use case. And to clarify your meaning of your phrase "alternately reversing polarities". As specified, pulses are not alternating. I think you realize that, but I believe it's an important point to make: the coil will never be able to discharge through the opposite FET.

Comment: An issue with the H-bridge or the version of it in your image is that the coil is represented as inductance without resistance. i.e. you have diode clamps in parallel with pure inductance when realistically there would need to be resistance in series with the inductance for it to be a coil.

Comment: @hazyj I had assumed the inductor in your circuit was the actual coil and the resistance was something you added so you could use a higher voltage supply than you otherwise could.

Comment: How can a coil be modeled realistically without including its resistance? I mean, in what cases would your clamp be realistic for L1?

Comment: I suppose that if there was extremely low resistance relative to reactance it works.

Comment: Half bridge: It's not entirely clear, but is R2/C1 an alternative to D5/D6? And if so, wouldn't the rating on C1 be 100s of volts given a hard digital signal and V = +/- 50V?

Comment: @PaulUszak I boxed them to show two independent approaches that could be used alone or together. With just RC snubbers, the cap voltage may need to be high but not because of the rail voltage. It has to do with C relative to L and I (energy in the magnetic field) since those determine what it charges up to. It presents a low impedance to the kick so the kick voltage is only as high as what the cap gets charged up to by the inductor's energy. Pulse caps and pulse resistors should be used.

Comment: @DKNguyen Hi DK. Not a complaint at all, but I think you might want to fix your H-bridge diagrams. I think 3 out of 4 FETs have incorrect images even though they're labeled correctly. A minor point of course, but just seems like something you'd want to fix. Again, a GREAT many thanks for all the help. -J

Comment: @hazyj Oh. You're right. I'm so used to all NMOS bridges that I didn't select a second MOSFET type.

Comment: Hey DK. I'll need to post a video URL for you to see later, but wanted you to know some surprising results I'm seeing. As an example I've wound my own coils, and am currently pumping 12 Amps though a 10 mH coil once every 0.8ms. Here's why I'm writing you: your H-bridge is discharging that same 12 Amps completely in less than 0.2 ms. Something I would never have guessed at. Rails are at +/- 60V. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I simulated a slightly modified version of your circuit in [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html). Here is the schematic:-

[image]

I don't have models for your FETs so I chose the nearest I could find in LTspice.

D1/C1/D2/C2 simulate typical DC power supply outputs. Less than 1 V of ripple was evident at a coil current of 0.5 A.

Q1 and Q2 act as current generators to level-shift the pulse inputs. This produces a Gate drive voltage of ~5.5 V (across R2 and R4) with supply voltages from 12 V to 50 V. Drive current is ~12 mA, which the ESP32 should be capable of (max. recommended GPIO output is 16 mA).

Zener diodes D3 and D4 protect the Gates against possible over-voltage, and C3 and C4 help to swamp out 'miller' feedback voltage. These components may not be necessary, but I put them in for peace of mind considering the relatively high Gate drive impedance of 470 Ω.

R8 damps ringing in the coil when switched off.

Here is a plot of the coil receiving positive current for 1 ms:-

[image]

The switching waveform was clean, R8 providing sufficient damping to produce a single flyback pulse with virtually no ringing. No extra flyback diodes or other damping components appeared to be necessary.

The slow rise time is caused by the coil's L/R time constant. Fall time is quicker because with backemf it has twice as much voltage. Backemf increases at the resonant frequency of the coil and parasitic capacitance in the FETs, taking less than half a cycle to reach the opposite supply rail where the other FET clamps it.

With a supply voltage +-50 V the peak voltage across each FET is slightly over 100 V. A margin of at least 20% is recommended, so you should choose FETs rated for 120 V or higher. With only 0.5 amps maximum coil current the FETs don't need to have very low on-resistance.

Comment: Wow - this is awesome Bruce!! I was about to wire a circuit to give a similar plot but with much more complicated logic. My drivers are similar to yours - as I mentioned the schematic for those was rushed. I won't keep belaboring why, but the logic is simple for me and wasn't supposed to be a focus. However, all the effort put in there is extremely well appreciated!

Comment: FYI, since you seem to be interested and since what I'm doing with this *is* interesting (IMO of course:-) ... the entire goal for me is to look at that plot and choose the shortest pulse width for my purposes. This isn't exactly on topic because heat dissipation will determine what I can get away with, and that dissipation rate will be completely determined by materials and structure and not in any way common EE practices. I have a handle on that part starting with choosing pulse width and duty cycle. So  according to your awesome plot ...

Comment: For my FETs I can choose +/- 42V rails max. I'll get a slightly longer rise time and lower output current than shown in your plot. I can easily ball park the min pulse width for my purposes here: 95% of peak value achieved in about 0.25-0.30 ms. Decay takes approx 0.1 ms: approx 0.3 - 0.4ms total. Duty cycle chosen by heat dissipation constraints. I will find max duty cycle for my purpose, and if still concern about heat pulses can simply be shut off for a reasonable amount of time. I've done this part before. Nothing difficult here *because* of appropriate pulse with choice.

Comment: Since your schematic is so incredible (and handy) I'd like to update my post and make reference to it. However, I don't know if that's appropriate and if it is how to give you credit beyond an upvote. Thoughts?

Comment: Oh, by the way I have so many FETs sitting around with no use case in sight I'd much rather use them than the BJTs. Completely aware that this changes the circuit, but am wondering about your thoughts in general regarding FET gate drivers wired up correctly.

Comment: I'm realizing your circuit will be confusing to others because you chose 5mH coil instead of the 40.8mH in my post. Just want to state it here that you and I discussed the general case of designing a circuit for variable LR with L being anywhere from 5mH to 100mH. It should be clear to anyone how to modify for my parameters stating in my the post.

Comment: I chose 5mH because that represents the most likely maximum current situation (the circuit works equally well with other coils such as 40.8mH+1k etc.). To avoid confusion perhaps you should add the full range of coil specs to your question.

Comment: Absolutely should. And I want to remove the FET drivers completely from my schematic prevent people from focusing on those, but I'm not sure that goes over well on EE SE. In any case, I realize that with 41mH and 140 ohm coils I end up with about twice the discharge period as with 5mH. As I stated I was wiring up a circuit to quickly discharge the coil (essentially short circuiting your R8 resistor when pulse stops). I may still do that.

Comment: Please don't put references to my answer in your question, it's fine as is (apart from not including the important extra info you put in the comments) and changing it could affect the relevance of other answers. Please remember that this site is **not** a discussion group. People mostly come here to get generic answers to questions like "Are external diodes needed to protect these MOSFETs from back emf?" that may relate to their own problems, and are not so interested in the minutae of your project.

Comment: To quickly discharge the coil you need to raise the flyback voltage. A short circuit will make it discharge slower. Again, your circuit is fine as is, don't change it!

Comment: I think you misunderstand my meaning of short circuit. Happy to show you what I mean. Absolutely will not slow discharge. This is simple energy conservation.

Comment: I updated the post and merely mentioned your name as someone who helped. Is that ok or do you want me to remove it?

Comment: oh boy. i completely didn't get that after coil is charged up through top FET it then discharges through bottom fet which i thought was off with Vd=Vg=Vs=-50V ish. so when Vds = 0 Rds goes low even when Vgs = 0?

Comment: _"I updated the post and merely mentioned your name as someone who helped. Is that ok". That's fine. Glad to be of help! Coil discharges through the body diode of the other FET, but only until the voltage drops below the supply rail. Then it rings, or in my case discharges through the resistor. The high resistance allows current to drop rapidly at that point.

Comment: it's obviously acting like a forward diode which i'm sure is exactly what it is in this case. need to brush up on that!! i'm obviously confusing body diode with the reverse diode in parallel. i see you just commented to that effect. Wow - so glad you made me realize this. Or remember it. It's been awhile:-( so yeah, nevermind my comment about short circuiting. i didn't realize that this is exactly what's happening albeit with that Vf diode drop.

Comment: nope. i had it right and no misunderstanding. phew! what i'm having trouble with is that coil and resistance are separated. I want to short circuit the coil without taking account of the resistance, or that's what my eyes are telling me to do. all that energy *must* go through the coil resistance obviously, but when your simulation scope shows different voltage across coil than across its resistance ... doesn't make any sense realistically. obviously i need to get used to these simulations.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do would be to determine the overshoot from the mosfet (best done in a simulation), once you do here is the things you need to worry about:

For a mosfet, two parameters found in the datasheet (Vgs and Vds) can't be exceeded or the device will probably fail.

Vgs is the voltage between the gate and the source, for many mosfets its around 15V or 20V.

Vds is much higher but also can't be exceeded.

For the top fet, it's Vgs that becomes a worry, if the inductor is say 40V and the gate at 0V then the gate could easily get blown out if the Vgs were ±20V. So in that case either select a mosfet that has a large Vgs (some go up to 50V, which would cover your application but may not have the other parameter needed for the design so select carefully) or use diodes to reign in the overshoot from the inductor.

Comment: I'm finally settling down and getting to my simulations. Concern about exceeding Vgs max has been one of my 2 or three main concerns leading me to post. Yes - current solution has diodes lessening the overshoot as well as RCs in parallel. I believe I've also addressed the possibility of exceeding Vgs but let's see what the simulation has to say. Thanks!!

Comment: One thing the moderators can't touch is voting, it wasn't a great question to start with so I can see a problem there. Another problem that I don't like with the question is a lack of a specific question statement.

Comment: fair enough. i'm moving on and, i assure you, improving as well.

Comment: No worries it takes a bit to get up to speed

Comment: Why would Vg ever stray far from +/- Vdd for the respective FETs? My schematic shows they will always be following the sources +/- a very well controlled drop due to the dividers shown. Since I stated Vgs +/- 2V (I meant threshold of course) I don't see why there would be any concern that Vg for top FET would ever dive below Vdd - 10V or for bottom FET above -Vdd + 10V.

Comment: Maybe i drew that FET incorrectly? I didn't think so. It's a pFET with source at top.

Comment: Nope. It's correct. There's no Vgs concern.

Comment: There probably won't be, but in designs like this that is the number one concern. When the inductor is released it can overshoot because the node between mosfets is floating (because they are both off) in that case the voltage can raise very high and hurt the mosfets

Comment: Still not following. Vg can never be out of bounds regardless.

Comment: Unless you're saying that Vg for the top FET can spike to something above Vdd + 20V?

Comment: In any case you specified my exact concern with this statement "the node between mosfets is floating (because they are both off) in that case the voltage can raise very high and hurt the mosfets". Thank you for being clear. This is why I posted: don't ever want Vds for either FET to exceed max which is very possible for this circuit. This is what I'm trying to get a handle on for this real world case. Maybe theory should be enough, but you guys have actually done all this and I want to be sure I have a grip on the main issues should they arise. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the MOSFETs should have body diodes pointed in the right direction for protection. Check out some datasheets from integrated fet H-bridges like this one, it's not the same circuit but similar principle.

TI DRV8833
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8833.pdf?ts=1608079490506&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: you know, one of the great reasons for asking question on sites like this is to get feedback from competent people that don't tell you "you've missed the point". answers like yours are refreshing because they get straight to the point: although I'm well aware that MOSFETs have body diodes and clearly will help, I still need someone with experience to confirm that they will be enough *for the circuit in question*. So now I can proceed to lessen overshoot and I believe I'll start seeing some nice looking pulses soon. Thank You!

Comment: Unless there is something I'm missing, you are talking about Vds exceeding the mosfet ratings due to back emf from the coil on the floating node between the two mosfets? That node is not floating it is clamped to +/- Vdd from the mosfet body diodes, which are not drawn in the schematic. In reference to the title's question, the external diodes aren't needed because the body diodes in the mosfets are already there.

Comment: Not following Colin, but then I'm probably missing something. Let's take an example. Each FET has Vds = 100V breakdown. Let's say Vdd is 50V for my circuit . When the top FET is conducting and then cutoff, the left side of the coil rises above 50V momentarily due to back EMF.  Vd from bottom coil is now at 50V+. Vds max has therefore been exceeded.

Comment: This shows max Vds exceeded (i.e. Vds > 100V in this case) if diodes are removed.  
 https://tinyurl.com/yaf2of5h    Vds plot is at bottom right. I got my voltage backwards in previous comment, so scope shows top Vds for top FET.

Comment: Look at this: https://tinyurl.com/y7vl94tj The voltmeter shows peak above Vds

Comment: I can't post a picture in this response but look up the datasheet for your PMOS, SUP70101EL. Draw the component in your schematic with the extra body diode as pictured on the first page. When the back emf from the coil exceeds Vdd + Vf for the body diode, it will start conducting and clamp that node voltage. As long as the power dissipation is not too great, Vds max will not be exceeded. R5 isolates FET's and coil slightly so I can't predict the exact effect.

Comment: I think you may be underestimating energy discharge in the coil Colin. One point of this circuit is to efficiently charge a powerful coil. If all is designed well then fine, but it must be designed around a coil with a large amount of energy discharging quickly *with no easy path to a sink*. I doubt that's a common case for my circuit.

Comment: please see Bruce Abbots answer which directly addresses the point we're discussing which is also the point of my post. to be fair, he understood my post only after we went back and forth a bit. i realize you wouldn't be able to guess at some of this without asking. my apologies and regardless you've been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The body diode of the opposite MOSFET is in the correct position to protect each MOSFET.

Body diodes are a bit slow and have normal silicon diode Vf. They can be paralleled with Schottky diodes if speed is required, but with 40mH it probably makes no difference.

The initial current through the body diodes will be the coil current and will die off exponentially with a time constant R/L. Your MOSFETs need to withstand Vcc*2 plus a bit. The “bit” needs to handle the diode Vf and any inductance in the power supply circuit. This assumes your supplies are have good bypassing and are well regulated, and have enough bleed current or can sink current to absorb the power from repeated switching.

If you just switch one MOSFET repeatedly, you have made a boost converter and the opposite rail could increase out of regulation if there is nothing to absorb the energy stored in the inductance each cycle.

There are a number of problems with your gate drive- most likely no MOSFET that works properly with 3V drive can withstand more than 8-20V, and the p-channel driver needs work. Also the switching may be too slow.

But you just asked about the diodes.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't worried about the gate driver at all. I just rushed it because a LOT of time was wasted trying to install TINA-TI on my mac. It isn't easy! Anyhow, that's why the question seems so off: time wasted didn't allow much time to post.

Comment: "Your MOSFETs need to withstand Vcc*2 plus a bit." This is one of the main reasons I posted. I've learned a lot about that "bit" since posting, and it's led me to what you just mentioned: good supply and grounds for sinking current for the large energy stored in the coil. I could design around FETs with larger Vds max, but the question would just come up again with different parameters. Anyhow, I don't like that "bit":-( Time to rid my concerns with it by discharging the coil superfast. Easy enough! Thanks Spehro